# CDbException: What does this mean?

Tags: database

This just happened, but just one time. Any idea why?

> CDbException
>
> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `id`, `groupId`, `name`, `handle`, `context`, `instructions`, `translatable`, `type`, `settings` FROM `craft_fields` WHERE context = :context ORDER BY `name`. Bound with :context='global' (/Users/johndoe/Desktop/Projects/websitetest/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:543)
>
> 0 /Users/johndoe/Desktop/Projects/websitetest/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(396): CDbCommand->queryInternal('fetchAll', Array, Array)
>
> ... (large, not relevant stack trace)
>
> 30 {main}

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is failing in local development on a Mac. My experience with native MySQL on OS X 10.9.3 is that the MySQL server just stops working once every few weeks, and I have to restart it. Since it's only occasional and I don't use it for anything really critical, I just live with the restarts.

Answer (score 2):

[CDbException](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbException) is the exception that [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) will throw when something has gone wrong with a database operation.

Here's the only important part of the error message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query.
```

Unfortunately that error can occur for any one of [3,210 different reasons](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQLSTATE%5BHY000%5D%3A%20General%20error%3A%202013%20Lost%20connection%20to%20MySQL%20server%20during%20query) including network connection errors, misconfigured PDO, MySQL and/or PHP, etc.  It's going to be difficult to track down especially if it's only occurring sporadically.